# Flutter-Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I'm starting developing apps with flutter, and I encounter with this error when I clone a project from **GitHub**:

What went wrong?

```
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
Android dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.0.2) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

**I'm running Android Studio 3.2.2 and Flutter SDK 1.2.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found a solution for the problem.
Only need to add the following code on the build.gradle  file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.media:media:1.0.0'
    }
}
```

Then, the app runs without any error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to migrate the project to Android X. You can only do this through Android studio 3.3.

[Follow the procedures here to Migrate your Project to Android X](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27128#issuecomment-457918930)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i follow steps posted in that link, but when i try to do migration to Android X i get the message "No usages found in the project", even after sync project with gradle files. I try do that with Android Studio 3.5 canary 6